# How to map routes dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

With a website, I am using the built-in routing tools available within the newer version of ASP.NET, but they aren't currently dynamic, they're hard coded into the codebase in the global.asax file.

Not sure if this is possible but, is there a way that those routes can be generated dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass [RouteBase](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970) in order to make your routes based on a dynamic data set.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class ProductRoute : RouteBase
{

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData result = null;

        string virutalPath = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1).ToLowerInvariant();

        // Call the database here to retrieve the productId based off of the virtualPath
        var productId = Product.GetProductIdFromVirtualPath(virutalPath);
        if (productId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
            result.Values["controller"] = "Product";
            result.Values["action"] = "Details";
            result.Values["id"] = productId;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData result = null;
        string controller = Convert.ToString(values["controller"]);
        string action = Convert.ToString(values["action"]);

        if (controller == "Product")
        {
            string path = string.Empty;
            if (action == "Details")
            {
                Guid productId = (Guid)values["id"];

                // Call the database here to get the Virtual Path
                var virtualPath = Product.GetVirtualPathFromProductId(productId);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(virtualPath))
            {
                result = new VirtualPathData(this, virtualPath);
            }
        }


        return result;
    }

}
```